# numpy arange for list (vectorized calculation)

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create a 2d matrix `b` from an array `a`, where `a` contains range_stop values for each matrix column.

For example, with `a = [2,3]`, I want to obtain

```
b = [[0, 0],
     [1, 1],
     [2, 2],
     [NaN, 3]]
```

What's the most efficient way (for vectorized calculation) to do it? My current code is:

```
a = [2,3]
b = np.zeros((max(a)+1,len(a)))
b.fill(np.nan)
for i,ai in enumerate(a):
    b[:ai, i] = np.arange(ai)
```

Comment: I have edited the question and its quite clear guys.. Can someone please answer?

Comment: @kmario23 is a dynamic array, with 2 values as just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first create the 2D `arange` using `repeat`

```
a = np.asarray([2, 3])
b = np.repeat(np.arange(np.max(a) + 1, dtype=float)[:, None], len(a), axis=1)
# array([[0., 0.],
#        [1., 1.],
#        [2., 2.],
#        [3., 3.]])
```

and then compare each column with `a` to fill in `np.nan`s

```
b[b > a] = np.nan
# array([[ 0.,  0.],
#        [ 1.,  1.],
#        [ 2.,  2.],
#        [nan,  3.]])
```